# Publicly exchanging keys

Tags: key-exchange

my use case is the following: Sharing a secret on the blockchain from one participant over a smart-contracts with revealing the secret only after some condition is verified (another participant has paid for it).

Since every content on the blockchain is publicly available, I'm looking for a cryptographic way of exchanging keys.

This use case should be quite common for smart-contracts.

Comment: [Authenticated Key Exchange over Bitcoin](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/308.pdf)

Comment: In general it is better to ask such questions on a site that is specific to blockchain, e.g. StackExchange has the [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) site which is also for other crypto currencies. Smart contracts seem to be more specific to [Etherium](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the notion you're secretly after is Verifiable Delay Functions.

They don't depend on a verifiable condition, they provide a way to ensure that no-one can compute them in a short time (even by massive parallelization).
They can be used during a synchronization step controlled by a smart contract.